# d3 click event not work using jquery.click

Tags: d3.js

```
g.selectAll("path")
  .data(features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", d3_path)
  .on('click', function(d){
        alert("x: " + d3_path.centroid(d)[0] + " y: " + d3_path.centroid(d)[1]);
        $("#path_" + d.properties.name).addClass4SVG('black');
                })
  .attr("id", function(d) {
         return "path_" + d.properties.name;});
```

Then I need to trigger the click manually.So I use

> $("#path_name").click()

, but the d3 click event not work.

How can I make the d3 element click event work? (I need the variable 'd')

Comment: Are you sure that you're selecting the same elements here?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qrauh5ov/

Comment: @nothing9 hi, I mean to click using $("id").click()

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for the click event if you are already using d3 which has its own click event? Not sure how you can access the d3 data (variable 'd') when using jQuery...

Comment: Same problem here. Did you found a solution?